# setVisibility from View.GONE state to View.VISIBLE not working properly

Tags: java, android

I have a real strange problem and I don't know how to solve it. 
I have a View inside a LinearLayout with attribute android:visibility="gone"
this is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="dfgdfg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:id="@+id/preLollipopShadow"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

when I want to change visibility of view with preLollipopShadow I use this code

```
if (newPosition == StickyHeaderLayoutManager.HeaderPosition.STICKY) {
                        ((ViewGroup)header).getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((ViewGroup)header).getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
```

it is not working as I expect , I want that shadow be visible on sticky mode and be gone otherwise .

how can I achieve that ?

UPDATE 1 :
When I start with visibility "invisible" and switch to "visible" and back it is working but not with starting state of "gone" on my preLollipopShadow view.

UPDATE 2 : 
The view is inside a RecyclerView , Does not updating view visibility somehow related to being nested into a RecyclerView ?

Comment: just a remark: you could use ternary operator instead of if: `view.setVisibility(newPosition == StickyHeaderLayoutManager.HeaderPosition.STICKY? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE)`

Answer (score 1):

The View you want to hide and show has an **id** of preLollipopShadow attached to it. Its easy to find the view by its id.

```
parentView.findViewById(R.id.preLollipopShadow);
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.preLollipopShadow);
```

if you want to reference the view from an activity.

Comment: It's not an activity it is a fragment , but I'll try and let you know

Comment: no it is not working , when I start with visibility invisible and switch to visible and back it is working but not with state gone

Comment: We will need a little more code. Are you using this code in a recycler adapter? etc.

Comment: yes the view is header of a section in recyclerView and I am using a library to get it sticky , for lollipop and up setElevation works fine but preLollipop I want to show a view as shadow under the title on start of being sticky